# get file descriptor at x from fd_set c++ linux

Tags: c++, linux, file-descriptor

I know on windows you can get a file descriptor by doing myfd_set.fd_array[x] but when I try and do that on Linux it does not work. What do I have to do to get a file descriptor?

Comment: Did you try reading the `fd_set` manual page? Type `man fd_set`, to get the information you're looking for. You already have all the documentation you need, to figure it out.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Which part of the `fd_set` manual page answers this question?

Comment: The one that explains the `FD_ISSET` macro?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik In what way does `FD_ISSET` give you the xth FD? Your condescension would no doubt be [slightly] more constructive if it were actually backed by any facts...

Comment: Simply by calling the macro, and if you have an issue with my comment you are welcome, as always, to flag it. Have a nice day.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik `FD_ISSET` tells you whether the FD with value _y_ is set. It does not give you, and has never given you, the xth FD in the set. The OP wants the FD at index `x`. Please read the question before launching into patronising remarks. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

There's no macro defined by POSIX to do what you're asking.

The technique you've used on Windows is viable because the structure of a descriptor set is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/ns-winsock-fd_set) on that platform, so you have reliable access to its innards.

Generally, you wouldn't need this functionality. I don't think I've ever seen a poll loop that needed to obtain the *n*<sup>th</sup> descriptor in an `FD_SET`. Usually, you add your FDs to a set, pass it to `select`, then — looping back over your descriptors — use `FD_ISSET` to see whether there is any activity on that file. Or, better yet, use [`poll`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) or `epoll` for a much more efficient and scalable approach.

I recommend you try to re-structure your code into a more common pattern, in order to obviate your requirement.